# Samba - AD cant login from diferent hostname

Tags: networking, server, samba, dns, active-directory

I installed samba with winbind and is currently running properly using the AD to auth clients via the server hostname and ip address.

However i would like the clients to be able to login to the share using a different hostname from my dns, but everytime i try to login it rejects the credentials, here is the output from smb log:

```
[2016/08/23 10:14:32.650746,  3] ../source3/smbd/smb2_negprot.c:271(smbd_smb2_request_process_negprot)
  Selected protocol SMB2_10
[2016/08/23 10:14:32.990048,  1] ../source3/librpc/crypto/gse.c:497(gse_get_server_auth_token)
  gss_accept_sec_context failed with [Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information: Request ticket server cifs/storage.mydomain.com@MYDOMAIN.COM not found in keytab (ticket kvno 1)]
[2016/08/23 10:14:32.990067,  1] ../auth/gensec/spnego.c:541(gensec_spnego_parse_negTokenInit)
  SPNEGO(gse_krb5) NEG_TOKEN_INIT failed: NT_STATUS_LOGON_FAILURE
[2016/08/23 10:14:32.990128,  2] ../auth/gensec/spnego.c:716(gensec_spnego_server_negTokenTarg)
  SPNEGO login failed: NT_STATUS_LOGON_FAILURE
[2016/08/23 10:14:32.991082,  3] ../source3/smbd/server_exit.c:252(exit_server_common)
  Server exit (NT_STATUS_CONNECTION_RESET)
```

How can i accomplish this?

Thank you

Comment: Post the share part of your /etc/samba/smb.conf